# Add-Shift Right algorithm - How does it work?

Tags: algorithm, multiplication, shift, accumulator, alu

So I have to build a basic 4 Bit multiplicator using only Add and Shift Right. I basically know how the Shift Add Algorithm works but I do not know how one would get it to work with right shifting instead of left shifting. From a technical standpoint, let us say we have one accumulator, two 4 Bit Shift Right Register and one ALU, it would basically look like this, considering that at the start the multiplicand is in the accumulator and the multiplicator in ShiftReg2, so that we can use the accumulator (Bit 7-4) and ShiftReg1 (Bit 3-0) as the Output for our 8 Bit product.
Acc=abcd   ShiftReg1=nothing important so far and   ShiftReg2=wxyz

Know how would start to get the 4 Step algorithm going considering you would have to always shift right and can only add your multiplicand to your accumulator?

Comment: How would you perform binary multiplication with pen & paper? Try 1000 x 1001. Also, SO is not a site to solve homework problems - if you've a problem with your code, show what you have tried, and describe how it failed.

Comment: Could you give us the whole list of available operations. I guess you have a ShiftRight on each of the 3 registers, an Add(ShiftReg1, Acc), an Add(ShiftReg2, Acc), 3 moving instructions, but what aboute bit-wise testing, AND/OR/XOR/NOT operators ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an instruction (called JPE) that jumps forward if the accumulator is even (just testing if the right-most bit is null), you can have this heavy/ugly solution.

Instructions :

- `JPE <address>`: If the accumulator is even, jumps to this address.
- `ADD <r1>, <r2>` : Add the value of `<r1>` to `<r2>` and stores the result into `<r2>`.
- `SHR` : Shift the accumulator 1 bit to the right.

Initialisation :

```
Acc : first number.
Sr1 : 0, but it will hold the result at the end of the algorithm's execution.
Sr2 : second number to multiply with the first.
```

Awfull algorithm :

```
0001   JPE 0003
0002   ADD Sr2, Sr1
0003   SHR
0004   JPE 0007
0005   ADD Sr2, Sr1
0006   ADD Sr2, Sr1
0007   SHR
0008   JPE 0013
0009   ADD Sr2, Sr1
0010   ADD Sr2, Sr1
0011   ADD Sr2, Sr1
0012   ADD Sr2, Sr1
0013   SHR
0014   JPE 0023
0015   ADD Sr2, Sr1
0016   ADD Sr2, Sr1
0017   ADD Sr2, Sr1
0018   ADD Sr2, Sr1
0019   ADD Sr2, Sr1
0020   ADD Sr2, Sr1
0021   ADD Sr2, Sr1
0022   ADD Sr2, Sr1
0023   SHR
0024   <STOP>
```